# ReportViewer WebForms Function SetDisplayMode

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm using ReportViewer.WebForms and needed something like function **setdisplaymode** from ReportViewer.WinForms.

Example from WinForms:

```
ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
```

Anyone knows how to do that in WebForms?

Comment: I am in need of similar property.